# Running all maven test cases in jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, devops

I am running maven test cases in jenkins but I can see only few of them are executing and few of them are skipping. But I want to execute skipped tests as well to run.
How can I execute those test cases as well which are skipping??
I am running a pipeline to build a component.
How can execute all the test cases in bulk so that no test case can be skipped.

Comment: The question is: Why are the test skipped? Skipped test means someone has defined them to be skipped... So turn off skipping the test (remove `@Ignore` JUnit3/4 or `@Disabled` JUnit Jupiter).. ? Or does your pipeline define `-DskipTests`?

Comment: sh "${mvnCMD} -s ${MAVEN_SETTINGS} -am clean org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent deploy -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true -Dtest=**/*Test.java test

Comment: this is my build script

Comment: Actually, how can I execute the test cases in bulk so that no test is skipped?

Comment: Just use `mvn test` if not `@Ignore` or `@Disabled` is used then all tests will run.. except there are some exclusions in your configuration which I can not see nor do I know that...